# Send an IPA for submitting at Appstore

Tags: deployment, app-store, ipa

I need an IPA to send for deploying at Appstore.So my question is How would he Proceed after getting the IPA although he had the iTunes Credential.

I am sending the the IPA by following Line

Product - Archive - Export - Save for iOS APPStore Deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode menu: Xcode / Open Developer Tool / Application Loader

Then press "Deliver Your App"

Comment: Suppose I am sending an ipa ,screens with app icon & iTunes credential  to my friend through mail or drive then how would he upload it at Appstore .

Comment: Please let me know know what are steps he should follow